# Serenity Cucumber4 Environment URL on Page Objects not working

Tags: cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Why does this not work?

When I run the feature file as "Run as Cucumber Feature" I get an error

`java.lang.AssertionError: Undefined default URL for page object PageObject`

**Page Object**

```
@DefaultUrl("page:register.page")
public class AccountCreationPage extends PageObject {
   ...
}
```

**Config File** (serenity.config)

```
environments {
  local {
    webdriver.base.url = "https://localhost"
  }
  demo {
    webdriver.base.url = "https://demo.example.com"
  }
  prod {
    webdriver.base.url = "https://example.com"
  }
  all {
    home.page = "#{webdriver.base.url}"
    register.page = "#{webdriver.base.url}/register"
  }
}
```

https://johnfergusonsmart.com/environment-specific-configuration-in-serenity-bdd/
shows the use of `@DefaultUrl("page:register.page")`

Serenity-Cucumber4. Java. Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the config file is required to have default as an entry

```
environments {
  default {
    webdriver.base.url = "https://localhost"
  }
  ...
  all {
    home.page = "#{webdriver.base.url}"
    register.page = "#{webdriver.base.url}/register"
  }
}
```